# Exception ,trying to run a picture on the app

Tags: flutter

When I try to let my flutter app show a picture(it's asset image),it throws the `exception` :

```
"Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1".
```

What should I do in such a case ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()

{
  runApp(Center(
    child: Image(
       image:AssetImage('images/mont.jpg'),


    )
  ));

}
```

the pubspec.yaml file is :

```
flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - images/mont.jpg
  - images/a_dot_ham.jpg
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code and content of pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: i tried to add code in the question but i can't submit it saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: can you add code snippet of image and the asset area of pubspec.yaml instead posting whole file

Comment: it's solved right now..another problem poped up ...when i run the code that should show a assetpicture and testing it on physical phone ..the pictrue does't show up..